# How can I introspect the signature of a Flex function?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

Given a function like

```
function printAndAdd( s: String, a: int, b: int ) {
  // ...
}
```

Is there any way to enumerate the arguments of the function (their names as well as their types) at runtime? Something like

```
for ( var arg: ArgumentDescriptor in printAndAdd ) {
    // arg.type yields the class object of the argument, i.e. 'String' or 'int'.
    // arg.name yields the name of the argument, i.e. 's' or 'a'
}
```

I have a list of event handlers which have different signatures, and I get the name of the event handler to call as well as an `Array` of objects. I could just [`apply()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Function.html#apply%28%29) the array to the function, but I'd like to do some error checking first to give better error messages.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [describeType()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#describeType%28%29) to find the information you seek. However for this to work the function **must** be `public`. Private methods will not be introspected by `describeType()`.

Assuming `printAndAdd` is a method of `MyClass`, you can do this:

```
var metadata:XML = describeType(MyClass);
//find all the 'parameter' nodes of any method called 'printAndAdd'
var params:XMLList = metadata..method.(@name == "printAndAdd").parameter;

for each (var param:XML in params) {
    var index:int = param.@index;
    var type:String = param.@type;
    var optional:Boolean = param.@optional == "true";
}
```

One thing you will not be able to find, is the name of the paramater, but I suppose its index may suffice for your goal.

If you need more powerful reflection than this, take a look at the [as3commons reflect library](http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-reflect/index.html).